# c++ program doen't function properly after autorun

Tags: c++, file, io, autorun

System : Windows 7
User Account Control : Enabled

I hava a C++ .exe program that logs key events and writes them to a file. I registered it to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run inorder to autorun.

- The program starts at Windows start-up
- It doesn't function properly (it doesn't output the key events to the file)

Perhaps it's UAC's fault ?
Then why other programs (which i have istalled) function properly. Do they register some other values perhaps?

Thanks in advance for every kind effort to answer this question

Comment: Where is the file being written to located? Is it in a location that can be written to without elevated permissions?